# In InfoPath limit people picker to a certain sharepoint group

Tags: 2010, infopath

Is there a way to limit the people picker control in InfoPath to a certain SharePoint group? I need to do this without writing any custom server code.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Yes, with People picker field in 2010, you can do it in two steps:

- Enter the URL to site to query for people/groups

[image]

- In the General Tab, limit the search/selection to specific groups/users. See below

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just be aware that when selecting a SharePoint group InfoPath uses the ID of the group, not the name.  That means that if you change the group name the picker will still work as expected.  If you develop in one environment and deploy to another, it most likely won't.

Comment: Even if it used the name, it wouldn't matter since Sharepoint still uses the first attributed name independently on further changes.  Anyway, how can it possibly influence the work with Infopath FUI, I wonder?